# How to cache AJAX results server-side in node.js

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, caching, node-static

Apparently, [express-static](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) and [buffet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffet) cache only static files in the server memory. Is there a middleware which will allow me to cache AJAX results in the server memory? I need this to be done because I am storing my images in MongoDB. Does the Varnish reverse proxy cache AJAX results?

Comment: There are solutions available . one would be redis cache . There could be simpler solution like memory-cache npm module

Comment: It's not overly hard to implement a simple cache yourself, either. For example: https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/simple-server-side-cache-for-express-js-with-node-js-45ff296ca0f0

Comment: Hmm... I am thinking perhaps the cached data can be gzipped and shared across threads. Moreover, there is a memory limit in node.js which prevents too much data to be cached...

Comment: Caching to disk is always an option, it will still be faster than re-calculating the response from scratch.

Comment: I think disk access is really slow, perhaps thousands of times slower than memory access and the computation involved. I am also wondering whether the default MongoDB WiredTiger engine cache is efficient enough alone.

Comment: If stuff is so cacheable, why don't you let clients cache it?